# Python insert values <= 1e-7 in a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I hava a python (2.7) function which performs a MySQL update query on a double value, when numbers are greater then 1e-7 everything works fine, the problem is that if the number is equal or smaller it updates the field with 0.

To actually see whats hapenning I've added some print statements to my code to output the `qry` (the performed query) and the `value` (the value to be inserted).

```
qry = 'UPDATE %s SET value_dbl = %f WHERE name = \'%s\' && board_id = %d' % \
      (self._getValueTableName(idx), value, valueName, self.boardInfo[boardName])

print value
print qry
```

If I use the value 1e-6 my output is as follows:

UPDATE temp_ctrl_1 SET value_dbl = 0.000001 WHERE name = 'pid_ki' && board_id = 9
9.99999974738e-06

As you can see in this case everything is ok. Now if use the value 1e-7 however;

> > UPDATE temp_ctrl_1 SET value_dbl = 0.000000 WHERE name = 'pid_kp' && board_id = 9
> >     9.99999997475e-07

The variable `value` is rounded to zero when the query string is constructed, how can I update a MySQL double field with a value smaller than or equal to 1e-7 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOUBLE`s can be inserted using scientific notation, so all you need to do is change your `%f` to a `%s` to get Python's string representation of the value rather than trying to round it to a floating point:

```
>>> value = 1e-7
>>> print value
1e-07
>>> print '%f' % (value)
0.000000
>>> print '%s' % (value)
1e-07
```

I agree with the sentiment expressed in the other answer, however, that you should really not be mashing up query strings with string formatting if you can help it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't format the string yourself

- This opens you up to injection attacks
- The floats are formatted as as string, causing you to throw away data

Instead, pass the string and the list of objects as two separate arguments:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE %s SET value_dbl = %f WHERE name = %s && board_id = %d',
               [self._getValueTableName(idx), value, valueName, self.boardInfo[boardName]])
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying here however in my specific application everything is running locally and I don't have to worry about injection attacks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. It's still good practice to get into, but what's important to your question is that it does also have the effect of maintaining arbitrary precision, by never converting to a string.